# How to use requester pays bucket with AWS Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to query data in the **requester-pays enabled** S3 bucket but I got the following 403 error. The Redshift IAM user has permission for the bucket. How can I read the data using Redshift Spectrum - give requester-pays parameter?

ERROR:

```
[XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid...
```

Comment: Check your RedShift IAM role

Comment: It has the `AdministratorAccess` policy.